# How do I correct this problem with python's pip

Tags: python, pip

ok so, I have a problem with pip that idk how to fix I checked youtube and there are no fixed so this is my last solution , I'd really appreciate it if you help me fix this

It tells me this in cmd, (in the correct path)

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "c:\python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Python39\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'```
````

Comment: What command emitted this error?

Comment: Are u using Ubuntu?

Comment: If you already have pip try for 'pip3' too

Comment: @PrakashDahal What version of Ubuntu has `C:\Python39` path?

Answer (score 0):

From the error message, it seems you donot have pip installed. First possibility is that you maybe using a virtual environment and you forgot to activate that.

Second possibility is same as the error is saying that pip is not installed.

Use the following command to check whether pip is installed or not;

```
py -m pip --version
```

if it runs without showing some error like `pip is not recognised ....` , then install pip by following the steps given in the link below;

https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/

**Suggestion**: i think you have virtual environment created but you forgot to activate that because pip is automatically installed after you install python.

Answer (score -2):

you can try this to update your pip module

```
>/bin/env python -m pip install --upgrade mymodule
```

Comment: Where is `/bin/env` on the operating system that has `C:\Python39` path? Well, even if it'd exist the solution wouldn't work: the problem "No module named 'pip'" would prevent `python -m pip` working.